# Can't create link to atom editor on OSX for atom or sublime editors

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext, atom-editor

First of all I do not have a directory /usr/local/bin, everything is loaded in /usr/bin.

The command

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/bin/atom
```

or the similar one for subl fails with the error:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
```

Operation not permitted.
Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* you don't have `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the directory /usr/local/bin, I changed the owner to root and I changed the accessing rights to 755.